# Side menu (help), onClick() opens (but I want it to close if one clicks else where outside the menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

On Click menu opens but problem is it stays open, I want it closed when user clicks outside the menu. 
Copy the code and save as HTML file and try run try it, if you like it, keep it.
if you there is anything confusing, do ask me, I'll answer soon as I.
it is sooooooooooo annoying!~ stackoverflow is not letting post a simple question,

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#ItemTree").click(function () {
                $("#SubContainer").toggleClass("SubContainer");
                $("#disabled").toggleClass("disabled")
            });
        });
```

```css
p {
            color: #fff;
            padding-left: 10px;
        }

        .SideContainer {
            background-color: #676464;
            width: 28px;
            height: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            border-right: 5px solid #676464;
        }

        .SubContainer {
            background-color: #333;
            width: 300px;
            height: 100%;
            margin-left: 28px;
            position: absolute;
        }

        .VText {
            transform: rotate(90deg);
            color: #fff;
            margin-top: 50px;
            position: absolute;
            font-weight: bold;
            left: -10px;
            letter-spacing: 3px;
        }

        .ItemTree {
            background-color: #808080;
            position: absolute;
            height: 200px;
            width: 100%;
            border-left: 5px solid #ff6a00;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

            .ItemTree:hover {
                border-left: 5px solid #0094ff;
            }

        .disabled {
            display: none;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="SideContainer">
        <div id="ItemTree" class="ItemTree">
            <span class="VText">Tree</span>
        </div>
        <div id="SubContainer" class="">
            <div id="disabled" class="disabled">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <p> Some type of content.</p>
                    <p> Some type of content.</p>
                    <p> Some type of content.</p>
                    <p> Some type of content.</p>
                    <p> Some type of content.</p>
                    <p> Some type of content.</p>
                    <p> Some type of content.</p>
                    <p> Some type of content.</p>
                    <p> Some type of content.</p>
                    <p> Some type of content.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="height: 1600px; width: 20px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code snippet doesn't seem to work. can you post a fiddle?

Comment: fixed it, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Add a click event to the document and check if the target (the element which triggers the click event) is a child of your subnavigation.

```
$(document).on('click', function (ev) {
  if (!$(ev.target).closest('#SubContainer').length) {
    $("#SubContainer").removeClass("SubContainer");
    $("#disabled").removeClass("disabled");
  }
});
```